How to identify heteroclinic (or homeoclinic) points on a mapping?
Identify the heteroclinic points of the following map:
\begin{equation}
    F\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1\\ \theta_2
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1+\epsilon\sin\theta_1\\
        \theta_2+\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
My attempt:
\begin{equation}
    F\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1\\\theta_2
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1+\epsilon\sin\theta_1\\
        \theta_2+\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
We  find the fixed points, by solving
\begin{equation}
    F\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1\\ \theta_2
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        0\\ 0
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &\theta_1+\epsilon\sin\theta_1=0\\
        &\theta_2+\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1=0\\
        &\theta_1+\epsilon\sin\theta_1=0\implies \theta_1=0, \pi\\
        &\theta_2+\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1=0\implies \theta_2=0, \pi\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Then we find the periodic points by solving
\begin{equation}
    F\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1\\ \theta_2
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1\\ \theta_2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &\theta_1+\epsilon\sin\theta_1=\theta_1\\
        &\theta_2+\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1=\theta_2\\
        &\epsilon\sin\theta_1=0\implies \theta_1=0, \pi\\
        &\epsilon\sin\theta_2\cos\theta_1=0\implies \theta_2=0, \pi\\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Classify the four points, $(0,0)$, $(0,\pi)$, $(\pi,0)$, $(\pi,\pi)$. Generate the Jacobian:
\begin{equation}
    DF\begin{pmatrix}
        \theta_1\\\theta_2
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1+\epsilon\cos\theta_1 & 0\\
        -\epsilon\sin\theta_2\sin\theta_1& 1+\cos\theta_1\epsilon\cos\theta_2
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
insert for each point and calculate the Determinant:
\begin{equation}
    DF\begin{pmatrix}
        0\\ 0
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
(0,0) gives an equilibrium point.
\begin{equation}
    DF\begin{pmatrix}
        0\\\pi
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1+\epsilon & 0\\
        0& 1
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$\text{Det}D(0,\pi)=1+\epsilon$ gives a source.
\begin{equation}
    DF\begin{pmatrix}
        \pi\\ 0
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        0& 1-\epsilon
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$\text{Det}D(0,\pi)=1-\epsilon$ gives a sink point.
\begin{equation}
    DF\begin{pmatrix}
        \pi\\\pi
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        1-\epsilon & 0\\
        0& 1-\epsilon
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
$\text{Det}D(0,\pi)=(1-\epsilon)^2$ gives another sink point.
Since we have equilibrium point, followed by source, followed by sink, and followed at last by another sink, then the heteroclinic point is the point between the equilibrium point and the sink, hence the source. The homoclinic point is the sink which is followed by a second sink point.
However, I am not sure that this conclusion of the heteroclinic and homoclinic points is correct. Any comments appreciated.
Thanks
